# Selectize.js not rendering options from server

Tags: c#, selectize.js

Using Selectize.js, I am able to retrieve data from the server but nothing appears in the drop down on the callback. Maybe it is the format of the data?

On the server, I'm using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to serialize a datatable (C#) and return the JSON object.

At a loss as to why the data isn't rendering.

Code:

```
<div class="sandbox">
    <label for="select-movie">Movie:</label>
    <select id="select-movie" class="movies" placeholder="Find a PO..."></select>
</div>

<script class="show">
    $('#select-movie').selectize({
    valueField: 'ID',
    labelField: 'PO',
    searchField: 'PO',
    create: false,
    options: [],
    render: {
        option: function (item, escape) {
            return '<div>' + item.PO + ' ' + escape(item.PO) '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function (query, callback) {

        if (!query.length) return callback();

        var dataString = JSON.stringify({
        prefixText: query
        });

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetUsers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: dataString,
        error: function () {
            callback();
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
            callback(msg.d);


        }
        });
    }
    });
</script>
```

Data returned from server:

```
{
    "d":"[
        {
            \"ID\":1,
            \"PO\":\"PO/REQ Number\"
        },
        {
            \"ID\":262,
            \"PO\":\"this po\"
        },
        {
            \"ID\":264,
            \"PO\":\"Test po\"
        },
        {
            \"ID\":267,
            \"PO\":\"Test PO 1\"
        }
    ]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from server (`msg.d`) is a `String`. It must be an `Array`.

You should check your `Default.aspx/GetUsers` method to return it.